# Python PIP on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

When I run python `pip` on a new brand Ubuntu 15.04 system with all updates installed, I get the following assertion error. This is with Python 2.7.x. I get a very similar result with Python 3.4.x:

```
  ➜  pip list
  adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.4)
  <...snip...>
  pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
  pyserial (2.6)
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 80, in run
      self.run_listing(options)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 142, in run_listing
      self.output_package_listing(installed_packages)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 151, in output_package_listing
      if dist_is_editable(dist):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 367, in dist_is_editable
      req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, [])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 299, in from_dist
      assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
  AssertionError
```

Comment: Interesting. Might be a bug in pip that it can't handle certain types of version numbering (though a pip maintainer could defer the bug to pyserial not using a proper version scheme). What version of pip are you using; have you upgrade to the most recent version? `pip install pip --upgrade`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Ubuntu 15.04 with `/usr/bin/python -mpip list` (pip 7.1.0, pyserial 2.6)

Comment: @Evert: OP might need `--user` parameter, to avoid permission errors

Comment: Did you use apt-get to install pip?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You mean `sudo`? `--user` won't put the (new) executable on `PATH` if I'm right.

Comment: @Evert: no. Don't use `sudo pip` on Ubuntu, let the package manager to manage the system installation. `python -mpip` finds `--user` version. PATH could be adjusted, to run as `pip`.

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get install pip` but then regular `pip list` without sudo. Do I do something differently?

Comment: Don't use apt-get to install pip at all, install using get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py, there always seems to be a lot more bugs when you use the apt-get version of pip

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no need for `get-pip.py`.  `python -mpip install -U --user pip` could be used, to update `pip` for the corresponding `python` executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should report this as a bug [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip). I can reproduce it in my Ubuntu 15.04 (64bit). The man page clearly states the `pip list` and `pip3 list` commands should simply list the packages, but in both cases they crash with `AssertionError` before completing.